# How to set $PATH in Ubuntu

Tags: environment-variables

I want to work with Zettair search engine (see [link](http://www.seg.rmit.edu.au/zettair/)). I installed it on Ubuntu 14.04, but I cannot install the Zettair executable in my PATH with following command. What should I do?

```
PATH=/usr/local/zettair/bin/zet:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zettair/bin/zet
```

The following codes work for the folder I run them. Therefore, by changing the folder I got the error again.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zettair/bin/zet
export PATH
```

Comment: Please post the output of `ls /usr/local/zettair/bin/zet`

Comment: Remove the last `zet` in `/usr/local/zettair/bin/zet`. `zet` is the name of the binary, you need to add the directory *containing* the binary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a directory to my path?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems you have included the file name in the path, which is wrong. The `PATH` must contain the directory that in turn contains the executable you want to run, not the executable itself.

Use this:

```
export PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/zettair/bin
```

This will work for the running session and all child processes only, you can make it permanent by adding it to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/zettair/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: If you want the PATH variable to be available at login and to other shells as well, export it to `echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zettair/bin' >> ~/.profile`