# Help adding directory to PATH environment variable in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, environment-variables

How do I add "/home/me/pycharm-edu-4.0/bin/" to my PATH environment variable? I've tried what's in [How to set $PATH in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/627346/how-to-set-path-in-ubuntu) and [What is the PATH environment variable and how do I add to it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141718/what-is-the-path-environment-variable-and-how-do-i-add-to-it) but I can't get it to work. 
What exactly should I change

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

to? Or should I comment it out and add a line underneath? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use something like:

```
PATH="$HOME/pycharm-edu-4.0/bin:$PATH"
```

or:

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/pycharm-edu-4.0/bin"
```

if you want a higher priority for default paths.

Comment: You left out the $HOME in your suggested paths.

Comment: Should `PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH` be changed or must be keept?

Comment: @pa4080 keep it, add the new line at the end of file.

Comment: I added quotes. Makes a difference if `$HOME` or `$PATH` includes space characters.

Comment: I tried both lines but neither one worked. I ended up using this solution - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Installing+PyCharm+on+Linux+according+to+FHS to create a link.

Answer (score 1):

1.Open a terminal from the bin directory of pycharm and type

```
./pycharm.sh
```

2.Go to Tools>>Create Desktop entry.Now you can just press the windows key and type pycharm to run it

Answer (score 1):

Using [fish](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/fish.1.html), the other answers didn't work for me.

But this did:

```
set PATH $PATH /home/me/pycharm-edu-4.0/bin/
```