# Start Android Studio from any directory

Tags: command-line, bash, android-studio

In the installation instructions for Android Studio they say:

```
3. [OPTIONAL] Add "{installation home}/bin" to your PATH environment
 variable so that you may start Android Studio from any directory.
```

I did that according to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709374/change-path-permanently-on-ubuntu). But how do I start it now? The problem is I need to execute a shell script `studio.sh` and I am afraid these are not visible for the `PATH` variable.

I should be able to call it in any directory in terminal by calling just `studio.sh`.

EDIT: more info

`studio.sh` runs the Android Studio

I followed the official installation instruction which came with the android-studio zip file (form official website).

I added

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Installs/android-studio/bin
```

at the end of `~/.profile`.

Adding more outputs:

```
$ ls -l $HOME/Installs/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 roman roman 6985 bře 21 18:26 /home/roman/Installs/android-studio/bin/studio.sh

$ echo $PATH
/home/roman/bin:/home/roman/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/roman/Installs/android-studio/bin/studio.sh

$ type studio.sh
bash: type: studio.sh: not found
```

Comment: What is the output from `locate studio.sh`?

Comment: I returns 1. No output.

Comment: @win `type studio.sh` might work better

Comment: @wjandrea `type -a studio.sh` might work even better :D

Comment: It says `bash: type: studio.sh: not found`. I guess this implies it's not in the PATH after all. I updated the question to show the instructions I followed. The path to `studio.sh` is certainly correct - I tested it with `cd`.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton `which` and `type` will only find executables in the path. But to add it to the path we need to know what directory it is in. For this `locate studio.sh` always works unless it isn't even installed on your system.

Comment: @win `locate` uses a database that's not updated immediately. I think you want to use `find` instead, e.g. `find ~ -name studio.sh -type f`

Comment: I don't what you mean by 'installed'. I can run android studio with this shell script, so I'd say it is installed. And we know the directory it is in: `$HOME/Installs/android-studio/bin`.

Comment: I think my question must be too confusing somehow. Sorry for that. I know the directory it (`studio.sh`) is in, how would I add it to the PATH otherwise?

Comment: @SlowerPhoton What is the output of `ls -l $HOME/Installs/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`? And the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @wjandrea true if just installed today the  `updatedb` command would have to be run first.

Comment: After running `updatedb` locate now finds it. Where are we heading with this?

Comment: @SlowerPhoton OK, then something doesn't add up. The script is executable, in the path, and the PATH is correct, but Bash doesn't find it.

Comment: Ok, I realize my question was indeed too confusing. I'll try to rephrase it. I want to be able to call the script in any directory from terminal. Easily. So nothing like /path/to/studio.sh but instead something simple like bash studio.sh or ./studio.sh. I believe that is possible because of the installation instructions (see it in the question).

Comment: This question had a similar solution: [How to set $PATH in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/627346/301745)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the last item in your PATH:

```
/home/roman/Installs/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

The problem is that items in the PATH need to be *directories* but you've added a *file*. I'm not sure how this happened since it doesn't match the `export PATH=...` line you posted.

Comment: You are right! It doesn't match it because I forgot I had been meddling with the variable before.

Answer (score 0):

First find out what directory `studio.sh` is in so you can add it to the path. Consider the following:

```
rick@alien:~$ locate --regex "wpasupplicant$"
/etc/network/if-down.d/wpasupplicant
/etc/network/if-post-down.d/wpasupplicant
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
/etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant
/mnt/e/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant
/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/wpasupplicant
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ which wpasupplicant
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ type wpasupplicant
bash: type: wpasupplicant: not found
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ ll /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 182 Oct 26  2015 /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant*
```

The file `wpasupplicant` is defined as an **executable** as defined by the `x` in `-rwxr-xr-x`.

There is also a remote possibility `studio.sh` isn't defined as an executable and still in the path. In this case the `which` and `type` commands will not find it but the `locate` command will still find it.

#### If the file was just created

Consider if the file was just created:

```
rick@alien:~$ cp .rm-kernels-ndx asdf.asdf
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ locate asdf.asdf
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ time sudo updatedb

real    0m3.460s
user    0m0.503s
sys     0m1.167s
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~$ locate asdf.asdf
/home/rick/asdf.asdf
```

You need to run `sudo updatedb` for locate command to find newly created files. The program `updatedb` is called automatically by `cron` but newly created files may not appear. After comments on this thread I decided to change my own `sudo crontab -e` to run `/usr/bin/updatedb` every five minutes.

#### After you find the directory

To add your directory to the path edit `~/.profile` and add the following:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/Installs/android-studio/bin" ] ; then
  PATH="$PATH:$HOME/Installs/android-studio/bin"
fi
```

Comment: studio.sh is defined as an executable. There are three "x"s.

Comment: So the locate command found it? What directory is it in?

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you've read the question. In $HOME/Installs/android-studio/bin directory. I knew it from the beginning and it is unimportant for what I want to achieve. I want to be able to type studio.sh anywhere in terminal (in any directory) and start Adroid Studio.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton Sorry I missed that edit.

Comment: @win Forget `updatedb`, just don't use `locate`. It's less flexible than `find` anyway. Use `find ~ -name studio.sh` instead.

Comment: @wjandrea the point is `locate` is blazingly fast across multiple partitions and drives including `ntfs` partitions as it doesn't have to navigate directories.

Comment: But why? I know where it is. I don't want  to argue with you. I am glad for your help. It's just that I don't understand why.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton I added how to correctly add the path to the answer. After this your `type studio.sh` should find it.

Comment: It is already in the PATH variable. And I have updated `~/.profile` already - I also used export PATH which I believe is necessary. All in all neither this was the original question. Let me rephrase it, because it seems to be too confusing. I want to be able to call the script in any directory from terminal. Easily. So nothing like /path/to/studio.sh but instead something simple like bash studio.sh or ./studio.sh. I believe that is possible because of the installation instructions (see it in the question).

Comment: As long as `studio.sh` is executable it will be called. To confirm your `export` worked as expected use `echo $PATH` in the command line.

Comment: Thanks I've resolved it by now. The problem was indeed the PATH variable.

Comment: @SlowerPhoton Yes I caught that on wjandrea's answer. I was busy with crontab and missed your edit 10 minutes ago where you accidentally had the file name in the path.